# Load lazy fetched entity

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a hibernate criteria which loads a list of TypeAbsence (my entity) with a lazy fetch. In one of my methods I need to load it eagerly since it is sent through json and the json is null when the object is lazy intialised.

I tried:

```
  for(TypeAbsence typeAbsence: toReturn){
        Hibernate.initialize(typeAbsence.getDesignation());
  }
```

But this doesn't work, when I debug with intellij and open the toReturn list, the objects are still lazy initialised :s

Is there a way to load the type absences eagerly after we got the list from the criteria ?

Here is the code

```
 toReturn = typeAbsenceCriteria.getResultList();

 /* Here I want to reload the lazy loaded objects in toReturn in a eager way and then return the list through json */
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Using the Criteria Query API, you can specify the fetch mode using `setFetchMode`

**Example:**

```
 List<Cat> cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Kitty%") )
    .setFetchMode("mate", FetchMode.LAZY)
    .setFetchMode("kittens", FetchMode.EAGER)
    .list();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this but the problem is that i don't want to fetch it eagerly every time. Most of the time I want to fetch it lazily. It is only this one time I want to fetch it eagerly. That's why I would like to reload the objects that I already fetched lazily, eagerly. Then I can send it through json.

Comment: Moreover what is really wierd is that I don't have any association. I have a criteria on the entity TypeAbsence in order to fetch TypeAbsence entities and it is the TypeAbsence entities which are lazy loaded. How can the primary bject I request be lazy loaded ? I always thought the lazy loading affects only collections attached to the object I am loading and the the object itself